# Convert an Excel table to X column and Y column

Tags: excel

I currently have an Excel table which I need it to be split into a XY table.

Excel table:

```
Name       NameDesc    Ability     AbilityDesc
-------------------------------------------------
12345      LongName1   Tennis      Whack balls 1
12345      LongName1   Golf        Whack balls 2
23456      LongName2   Swim        Like a fish  
23456      LongName2   Run         Like a cheetah
34567      LongName3   Gaming      Starcraft
45678      LongName4   Run         Like a cheetah
45678      LongName4   Golf        Whack balls 2
```

Output table:

```
            12345    23456     34567    45678
---------------------------------------------
Tennis        X
Golf          X                           X
Swim                   X
Run                    X                  X
Gaming                           X
```

Is there a function in Excel that I can use? Or do I need to go VBA?

Comment: there is no *function* that does that for you. A Pivot table or VBA is the way to go

Comment: You would have to prepare the Horizontal (Ability) and Vertical (Name) list of your requirements and use Index and Match.......

Comment: A pivot-table works fine. Just add a new column with "X" everywhere and put count of x as value. Use format "X;;" in the table to display X instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

It can be arranged without a PivotTable but then a helper column is useful to distinguish between valid entries for a lookup. Say add a column (say A) containing `=B2&" | "&D2` copied down to suit and, assuming `Name` label is in B1 and your output table (already labelled for row and column)  starts in J1:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(K$1&" | "&$J2,$A:$D,4,0)=$J2,"X",""),"")
```

in K2 copied across and down as applicable might suit.